# Jsp:param not work in Liferay

Tags: jsp, liferay, jstl

I'm trying use a tag jsp:include and jsp:param on my portlet, but without success. I add the propertie theme.jsp.override.enabled=true in portal-ext.properties it did not work well.

**home.jsp**

```
<h2>${title}</h2>    

<jsp:include page="list.jsp" >
   <jsp:param name="list" value="${productList}" />
</jsp:include>
```

**list.jsp**

```
<ul>
<c:forEach var="product" items="${param.list eq null ? list : param.list }">
    <li>${product.name} - ${product.qt}</li>
</c:forEach> 
</ul>
```

The param every is null

Answer (score 3):

Try using c:set with request scope like below:

```
<c:set value="${productList}" var="list" scope="request"/>
<jsp:include page="list.jsp" ></jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally jsp:param doesn't work inside a portlet with jsp:include, try this:

```
<liferay-util:include page="list.jsp">
      <liferay-util:param name="list" value="${productList}" />
</liferay-util:include>
```

Maybe jstl will cause trouble if you use with liferay tags like this, if this is the case try this:

```
<liferay-util:include page="list.jsp">
      <liferay-util:param name="list" value="<%=request.getParameter("productList")%>" />
</liferay-util:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` to the top of your jsp file